# Python: why is my code not printing?

Tags: python

See the last four lines:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
print "we're going to erase %r." % filename

txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
print "If you do not want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."
raw_input("?")
print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')
print "Truncating the file. Good bye!"
target.truncate()

print "now I'm going to ask you for three lines."
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
target.close() #Need to close the file when done editing, or else cant open.

print "Here's the updated file!"
txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

I'm trying to display the updated file on the command prompt, but its not printing, the last line printed says "Here's the updated file!" Where is the updated file?!?!

update: i got it to work, I forgot to include a line "target = open(filename, 'w')", I tried to make it easier on the eyes by deleting my comments, however, i accidentally deleted this important peice. It is now printing what I want as well. Thanks for your help, I'm not sure why its working now.

Comment: Something is wrong with that script. Where is `target` assigned to, for instance?

Comment: You're not posting the code you're running.  If you ran this code you would get a NameError for `target`, since you don't define any variable called `target`.

Comment: It would also help if you posted the text of any error messages you receive. If it runs without error messages, than suggests that the file is empty- have you manually opened the file to confirm that there is information there to print?

Comment: update: i got it to work, I forgot to include a line "target = open(filename, 'w')", I tried to make it easier on the eyes by deleting my comments, however, i accidentally deleted this important peice. It is now printing what I want as well. Thanks for your help, I'm not sure why its working now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to close and re-open the file.

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
target.close() #Need to close the file when done editing, or else cant open.

print "Here's the updated file!"
txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

You just need to open the file in 'w+' mode and then you can `seek()` to position `0`; the start of the file.

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
target.seek(0)

print "Here's the updated file!"    
print txt.read()
```

When you open the file for writing with 'w' or 'w+', it will delete the file content- there is no reason to `truncate()` it.